# RegEx help- Express routing url

Tags: regex, node.js, express, routes

I've read from other Stack Overflow posts that you can use regular expressions to route various URLs. I've never really used RegExps before, so I need some help. How would I route all URLs that begin with /lobby/ followed by ten digits? Like so

```
app.get("/lobby/0000000000", function (req, res) ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
app.get(/^\/lobby\/[0-9]{10}$/, function(req, res) {
  // route handler here
});
```

Alternatively, you can use parameter checking:

```
app.param(function(name, fn){
  if (fn instanceof RegExp) {
    return function(req, res, next, val){
      var captures;
      if (captures = fn.exec(String(val))) {
        req.params[name] = captures;
        next();
      } else {
        next('route');
      }
    }
  }
});

app.param('id', /^[0-9]{10}$/);
app.get('/lobby/:id', function(req, res){
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was almost there.

Comment: In your example `captures` is a list of results not a single value, is this expected value for req.user.id ?

Answer (score 5):

```
app.get('/lobby/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log( req.params.id );
    res.end();
});
```

or

```
app.get('/lobby/((\\d+))', function(req, res){
    console.log( req.params[0] );
    res.end();
});
```

or if the URL needs to be exactly 10 digits:

```
app.get('/lobby/((\\d+){10})', function(req, res){
    console.log( req.params[0] );
    res.end();
});
```